# 'folly/folly-config.h' file not found

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, cocoapods, folly

I'm having this problem when I want to run the application via xcode

Showing All Errors Only
/Users/ugur/Documents/Projects/MyApp/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact/JSBundleType.h:10:10: 'folly/Portability.h' file not found

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  # Required by RNFirebase
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.15.0'

  # [OPTIONAL PODS] - comment out pods for firebase products you won't be using.
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Functions', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '~> 5.15.0'
  # pod 'Firebase/Invites', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.13'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.9'
  pod 'RNIap', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-iap'

  pod 'Folly', :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"


end
```

Comment: did you run `pod install` in ios folder?

Comment: Yes, I tried but not resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved clean everything

```
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-* && watchman watch-del-all && npm cache clean --force && npm cache verify && rm -rf ios/build && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm i
```

after tried

```
rm -rf Pods && pod install
```